# Validation for an associative array in Laravel

Tags: php, json, validation, laravel

I have a JSON structure like this which I want to validate.

```
{
  "result":[{

            "product_id": 1,
            "client": 49,
            "ticket": 2,
            "sold_from_date": 1431588871,
            "sold_to_date": 1433122200,
            "discount_given":18,
            "cheques":[{
              "cheque_number" : 123456,
              "amount": 6000,
              "cheque_date": 1433122200,
              "bank": "UCD"
            },
            {"cheque_number" : 456234,
              "amount": 6000,
              "cheque_date": 1433122200,
              "bank": "AMB"
            }
            ]
        },
          {

            "product_id": 1,
            "client": 49,
            "ticket": 2,
            "sold_from_date": 1433122200,
            "sold_to_date": 1434688959
        }]
}
```

I want to validate this JSON in Laravel.

I tried doing this:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($data, []);

        $validator->each('result.product_id' , ['required|numeric']);
        $validator->each('result.sold_from_date' , ['required|numeric']);
        $validator->each('result.sold_to_date' , ['required|numeric']);
        $validator->each('result.cheques.cheque_number' , ['sometimes|required|numeric']);
        $validator->each('result.cheques.amount', ['sometimes|required|numeric']);

        return $validator;
```

I am getting this error every time:

***Attribute for each() must be an array.***

Also, how can I validate cheques? Because it can or cannot be in JSON.

Comment: After going through the problem, I read that each method does the task.

Comment: How about you write `ProductValidator` class and you loop through every object in the `result` and pass it to the `ProductValidator`. If it fails for one, return `false`.

Comment: Yes, I could have done that here too. But, that's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `array` from `json` with `json_decode` function.

Try:

```
$dataarray = json_decode($data);

$validator = \Validator::make($dataarray['result'][0], [
    'product_id' => 'required|numeric',
    'sold_from_date' => 'required|numeric'
]);
```

iterate the array:

```
$roles = array(
    'product_id' => 'required|numeric',
    'sold_from_date' => 'required|numeric'
);

foreach($data as $element)
{
    foreach($element as $value) {
        $validator = \Validator::make($value, $roles);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I meant to say was I am already doing `$data = json_decode($input_data);`

Comment: The edit doesn't work. `Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Validation\Validator::each()`

Comment: I think the problem is that you add to each function a multidimension array.

Comment: So, how would it affect?

Comment: You add to each function $data["result"][0]

Comment: But that only validated 0th index.